# Shortcuts for Mac Users: Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, shortcut

I want to use a shortcut to autocomplete System.out.print in **Java**, I read that I should use Ctrl+Space, but I have a mac and when I do Ctrl+Space it shows Spotlight Search, do you know if there is another way for mac users?

The shortcut in Eclipse is: (Write) **sysout** and press Ctrl+Space

Comment: You can try cmd+space, also look here: https://www.shortcutfoo.com/app/dojos/eclipse-mac/cheatsheet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you've done something strange, Spotlight Search defaults to Cmd+Space across the entire system and is why Content Assist in Eclipse defaults to Ctrl+Space, just like on other OSes. You can reconcile the key mappings from the system Settings' Keyboard>Shortcuts panel, by choosing Spotlight there, and Eclipse's Keys preference page, by searching by name for "Content Assist".

[image: macOS Settings]

[image: Eclipse Preferences]

Answer (score 0):

If it's useful to someone: I deactivated the key combination "Select previous input source", that can be found in System Preferences -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts -> Input Sources. Another key combination can be easily assigned in the same window, if you need a shortcut for this.

After deactivating this default key combination, the key combination of ctrl + Space or ^Space autocompletes "sout" to "System.out.println" in Eclipse.

[Screenshot of keyboard settings in macOS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mD1ur.png)